# how to pick a category name if i chose a news of that category

Tags: php, sql

I am setting a query where i chose an ID of news to show that specific id news, i have a foreign key of  category table as category ID in news table, now i want that if i show a news i show title of category also.

I have tried picking up the category id which show only the id and i want to show the title of that category.

```
<?php
        if(isset($_GET['news_id'])){
         $the_news_id = $_GET['news_id'];
        }
   $query = "SELECT * FROM news_title WHERE news_id = '$the_news_id'";
        $select_all_news_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_news_query)){
            $title = $row['news_title'];
            $description = $row['news_description'];
            $image = $row['news_image'];
            $news_cat_title= $row['news_cat_id'];
        ?>
        <h1 class="page-header">News Page</h1>

        <!-- First Blog Post -->
        <h2>
            <a href="#"><?php echo $title;?></a>
        </h2>


        <img class="img-responsive" src="image/<?php echo $image; ?>" 
alt="abc">
        <hr>
        <p><?php echo $description; ?></p>

        <hr>
<?php  }
        ?>
        <!-- Second Blog Post -->
        <hr>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h1 class="page-header">
  <!--This is where i want to show title but i am getting the ID--!>
                 <?php echo $news_cat_title; ?>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
```

i expect to get the title but i am getting a number.

Comment: You are trying to display this one $description;?

Comment: <?php echo $news_cat_title; ?> this is where i want to get a title but i am getting an ID

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the schemas for the various tables it is hard to say for sure if I interpreted the question correctly but I assume what you are trying to do is join two tables? If you can you add relevant table schemas it would help.

```
select * from news_title t
left outer join category c on c.category_id=t.category_id
where news_id = '$the_news_id'
```

Based upon your last comment that the category table is simply called `category` and the foreign key is `cat_id`

```
select * from news_title t
left outer join category c on c.cat_id=t.cat_id
where news_id = '$the_news_id'
```

Then, when displaying the recordset you should be able to:-

```
echo $row['cat_title'];
```

An easy way ( on windows ) to capture and display the table schema:

- Open `cmd` prompt
- type `mysql -u root -p <DBNAME>` ~ changing  for the actual database!
- type `describe <TABLE>;` - press return
- copy displayed info and paste into text editor
- Repeat for all tables of relevance

Comment: i want to know how to put a proper join statement, i have news,table where all news are put with a cat_id as a foreign key where it takes from a category table where all the cat_id and cat_title are mentioned.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM news_title JOIN news_cat ON news_title.news_cat_id = news_cat.news_cat_id WHERE news_id = '$the_news_id'"; this was how i got it right, very helpful from you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code :

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['news_id'])){
 $the_news_id = $_GET['news_id'];
}

$query = "SELECT N.*, NC.cat_id AS news_cat_id
FROM news_title AS N
LEFT JOIN news_category AS NC
ON N.cat_id = NC.cat_id 
WHERE news_id = '$the_news_id'";

$select_all_news_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_news_query)){
    $title = $row['news_title'];
    $description = $row['news_description'];
    $image = $row['news_image'];
    $news_cat_title= $row['news_cat_id'];
?>
<h1 class="page-header">News Page</h1>

<!-- First Blog Post -->
<h2>
    <a href="#"><?php echo $title;?></a>
</h2>


<img class="img-responsive" src="image/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="abc">
<hr>
<p><?php echo $description; ?></p>

<hr>
<?php } ?>
<!-- Second Blog Post -->
<hr>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="page-header">
<!--This is where i want to show title but i am getting the ID--!>
         <?php echo $news_cat_title; ?>
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

The query statement based on your question and comments is maybe like this :

```
$query = "SELECT N.*, NC.cat_id AS news_cat_id
FROM news_title AS N
LEFT JOIN news_category AS NC
ON N.cat_id = NC.cat_id 
WHERE news_id = '$the_news_id'";
```

Comment: "SELECT * FROM news_title JOIN news_cat ON news_title.news_cat_id = news_cat.news_cat_id WHERE news_id = '$the_news_id'";

I have tried and got the result through this method.